# Is there any way to discover all smart TVs available and pair to one of it in android to create remote

Tags: android, controls, television, pairing

So, basically what I want to do is to discover all smart TVs in a hall and get list of it and display on recycler view. Then click one of it and pair it. After pairing is done, I will have a remote which will control the android TV. I am new to android so I don't know how to code it. Any answers or assistance will be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.